# WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException - the specified window type -1 is not valid

Tags: android, intentservice

I am trying to inflate UI elements from service. But getting `WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException - the specified window type -1 is not valid` error.
My code is like below,

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, null);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT));

windowManager.addView(layout, params);
```

I am getting this error,

```
android.view.WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@8b06417 -- the specified window type -1 is not valid
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:725)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.firebaseapp.privacy.MyIntentService.handleAction(MyIntentService.java:33)
    at com.firebaseapp.privacy.MyIntentService.onHandleIntent(MyIntentService.java:20)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Have you added permission in manifest file?

Comment: what permission needed to add? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add permission in the manifest

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Also try adding params type

```
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: whats the android version of your device ? i think you have to allow the permission

Comment: I am using 7.1.2 and all permissions are granted.

Comment: try allowing permission manually , in settings -> app permission-> special permissions check it

Comment: thats great, m happy i was helpfull ,happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168790/discussion-between-vivekrajendran-and-abdul-kawee).